# Remote Desktop Connection over VPN on mac

Tags: macos, networking, vpn, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to a Windows computer on over a VPN connection using Remote Desktop connection.
I opened Network on mac and created a new connection.

Interface: VPN.
VPN Type: PPTP.

I filled the inputs for server address, account name, password and applied.
I connect the VPN and it connects. I open Remote Desktop Connection and put the IP of the machina i want to connect but it dont connect, a problem occurs saying that the machina may be turned off and etc. But in a windows machine I can connect there and the machine is up and running. On my mac I ping to the ip address that a want to connect and it has no response.

I think that the vpn have a problem, is there a way for me to certificate that i am on the vpn network ? Whats going on?

Comment: You should post it on superuser.com, not here

Comment: sorry, i dont knew that.

Comment: How can i remove this from here?

Comment: I think you can just close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran into this today. Looks like when you configure VPN in OSX, if you try to send traffic to a different subnet than what your vpn is connected to, it sends it out your normal interface as opposed to the tunnel. TO mitigate this, head to your VPN settings, click advanced and make sure "send all traffic through vpn" is selected.

If this is selected, then it's probably firewall configs and your SOL until you can get in and modify them.